# Determining what has been added/deleted/changed in a Firestore list

Tags: javascript, angular, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

Firestore as the backend. I've managed to get through by simply using basic crud methods. However, I wanted to find out how do I determine the changes to a list of items that are returned after the initial subscription.

What I'm ultimately looking to do is :
- miminise the amount of documents that are read each time
- animate a list of items (entry animation, exit animation, change animamtion)

In the following example I have the basic crud method along with the initial subscription:

```
posts:post [] = [];

constructor(private db: AngularFirestore){}

ngOnInit(){

//The initial subscription to the posts
this.db.collection("Posts").valuechanges().subscribe( _posts => {
this.posts = _posts;
});


async addItem(_post:post)
{
_post.id = this.db.createId();
await this.db.collection("Posts").doc(_post.id).set(_post);
}

async update(_post:post)
{
await this.db.collection("Posts").doc(_post.id).update(_post);

}

delete (_post:post)
{
await this.db.collection("Posts").doc(_post.id).delete();

}
```

With the above methods, I'm subscribing to the documents in the Posts collection. Initially I'm receiving an arrray of type Post, and whenever another item is added, updated, removed i'm receiving an updated array of of type post.

How do I differentiate what has happened to the item so I can animate the changes (i.e animate the entry of the item etc...) ?

It would really help me out if you could show a sample code ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `valueChanges` observable only exposes the actual data in the document. It has no other metadata about the document, nor the kind of change.

If you need more information, listen for `documentChanges` instead. That exposes a stream of `DocumentChangeAction` objects, which amongst others contain a `type` property that is the `DocumentChangeType`.

See https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/firestore/documents.md#the-documentchangeaction-type